# Rullo solving strategy for 2-4

Tags: mathematics, strategy

How to eliminate/nominate candidates without guessing?

For the 3s it's quite easy because of the odd numbers but how to get further?!

[image: Here's the image]

For thoose who don't know the game, here's a short introduction:
[image]

Comment: Hey @Mat and welcome to Puzzling.Se. Can you please add more details to this questions because as it it now, I can't really understand what you're asking. As such, I strongly advise you to check out the [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and get a [Tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site. Happy puzzling :D

Comment: The first column must include the 2, but after that it seems difficult.

Comment: Hi, Mat. This seems to be a good question. However, on this site, questions should be self-contained in the sense that they shouldn't rely on external resources to be understandable. Could you please add the rules for Rullo to the question to make it so?

Comment: [This previous Rullo question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54201/solving-a-rullo-puzzle) includes a description of the rules.

Comment: "play by the rules". I see the point. I copied the "rules" from the previous post. However I don't think it's very useful to explain the game metrics in every question again and again. The game is available on Android and IPhone. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.akkad.rullo&hl=de_AT. However this may be a topic for meta.....

Comment: what's the '20' on the lower left/right edges?

Comment: At this point I would probably make a guess, and if that turned out wrong, backtrack. A good option to guess is to include the $4$ in the first column, third row from the bottom (sum $23$). The reason is that this immediately determines that column and row, leading to many forced moves, quickly leading either to a solution or a contradiction.

Comment: @jonmark it's the sum of the row.

Comment: @Mat The 20 is the sum of the row? How can that be when the 3 is active? Am I just missing something? Thanks

Comment: @Dewey823 4+3+4+2+3+2+2 =20. The "target" value for this row is 14. When you press the square with the 14 the tooltip appears which tells you the actual sum of all active candidates. If you press another square the tooltip appears for the other row...

Comment: @Mat got it, I thought the tooltip was for the row above (row 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic grid puzzles are generally supposed to have a unique solution. This Rullo puzzle has several solutions (unless there is some rule we are missing), so I would consider it an invalid puzzle. Here are four such solutions.

> The top two solutions are what I got when I chose to include the 4 in the first column, 3rd row. This eventually (after I think one or two more guesses) led to a situation with only four undetermined cells arranged in a rectangle all with a 2. One diagonal pair had to be included, the other excluded, but both were possible.
>  The other two solutions are what I got when I chose to include the 4 in the first column, 6th row. This led to about 6 undetermined cells where there were two ways to choose from.
>  There may be even more solutions.
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

> Added in green, in column one you need 6 more to make 16 and there is only one two
>  [image]

Comment: Nice didn't see that. But further on?

Comment: I haven't had much time to look at it, but that 2 means both 4s in that row can't be on (but one can)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the solution:

> Green means keep, red means don't 
>  [image: My solution] 
>  After getting to where you were I kind of made educated guesses based on areas that had rows and columns that needed to get rid of the same values.